# How to solve yarn build error - Error: ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir '/frontend/out/node_modules/cacache/node_modules/.bin'

Tags: node.js, docker, next.js, yarnpkg

I am deploying project with NextJS, Django, Postgres, Nginx in Docker Compose, it works fine in local (ubunutu 18.04). But in the server (ubuntu 20.04) it raises `Error: ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir '/frontend/out/node_modules/cacache/node_modules/.bin'` error. How to fix this.
P.S. I am using wait-for.sh for frontend to wait for api service to be ready(otherwise I also get build error) and my local docker version is `Docker version 19.03.12, build 48a66213fe`, my servers docker version is `Docker version 19.03.11, build dd360c7` maybe possible causes of the error?

My Dockerfile for frontend service:

```
USER root
WORKDIR /frontend
COPY . /frontend

# Add wait-for-it
COPY wait-for.sh wait-for.sh
RUN chmod +x wait-for.sh

RUN yarn
```

My docker-compose.yml:

````
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:12.0-alpine
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=purple_postgres_user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=purple_p@ssW0rd
      - POSTGRES_DB=purple_db
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    #    command: ./manage.py purple.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - ./backend/:/home/purple_user/purple/
      - static_volume:/home/purple_user/purple/static/
      - media_volume:/home/purple_user/purple/media/
    expose:
      - 8000
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    env_file:
      - ./.env.dev
    depends_on:
      - db
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/var/www/staticfiles/
      - media_volume:/var/www/mediafiles/
      - build_folder:/var/www/frontend/
    depends_on:
      - web
  frontend:
    container_name: frontend
    build:
      context: ./frontend
    volumes:
      - build_folder:/frontend/out
    depends_on:
      - web
    command: ./wait-for.sh web:8000 -- yarn build
volumes:
  postgres_data:
  static_volume:
  media_volume:
  build_folder:```
````

Comment: What produces the error (`RUN yarn` in the Dockerfile)?  Do you have a `.dockerignore` file to cause that folder to be excluded from the image?  What's the `CMD` that image is supposed to run?

Comment: In my case, it was due to the fact I had an explorer window opened in the directory I was trying to delete

Comment: is live server extension is installed?

Comment: @DavidMaze the error raises in the last step, which is specified in the docker-compose file, frontend services command specification. The images CMD is specified in docker-compose file which is ```./wait-for.sh web:8000 -- yarn build```. ```wait-for.sh``` is a script I use for service to wait for another service. and after that ```yarn build``` command gets executed and that is where error raises.

Comment: @Ashok nope, not any windows are open and live server extension isn't a case either. Because I run ```docker-compose up``` command in the server. The error gets raised in the server, not in local.

Comment: I think that, this can be due to ```wait-for.sh``` script. Because, it starts front service up to a point, then, it waits for web service to start and after that it tries to continue the frontend service, which maybe tries to delete a folder that is not empty. But, without this script I also get build error, because getStaticProps function needs to use the ```web``` service.

Comment: Do you know any command for yarn build which force remove the directory it tries to remove or something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, the solution was, to delete the volume of frontend service, which is named `build_folder`. To get correct name of the build folder you can run `docker volume ls` - for me it was purple_build_folder - and the delete folder by running `docker volume rm [volume name]` command.

Answer (score 1):

Named volumes in Docker are persistent.  When your `docker-compose.yml` file has

```yaml
volumes:
  - build_folder:/frontend/out
```

it causes the results of the previous build to be stored in the `build_folder`, and they are still there the next time this container runs.  That's what leads to the error message you see.

I'd avoid setting up a Compose service just to build files for some other service.  Instead, use a [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) to construct the artifacts at image build time.  Instead, in your Nginx image Dockerfile, build the front-end application:

```sh
FROM node:12 AS frontend
WORKDIR /frontend
COPY frontend/package.json frontend/yarn.lock .
RUN yarn install
COPY frontend .
RUN yarn build

FROM nginx
# ... whatever this Dockerfile had before ...
# (except, change `COPY stuff /image/path` to `COPY nginx/stuff /image/path`)
COPY --from=frontend /frontend/out /var/www/frontend
```

You can use a similar technique to `COPY` the static files `--from` your `web` image; either use an additional build stage, `COPY` them directly from the build context, or `COPY --from` the name of the separate built image.  (This is a little harder to orchestrate since Compose won't order dependent builds.)  This avoids a similar problem where the contents of `static_volume` hide changed static files in both images.

```yaml
services:
  nginx:
    # The build context must be an ancestor of anything that
    # it needs to `COPY` in.  Since we `COPY` from both the `frontend`
    # and `nginx` directories, we need to specify
    build: .
    ports: ['80:80']
    depends_on: [web]
    # No `volumes:`; the image is self-contained
  # No build-only `frontend` container
```

Comment: But, why that works in my local computer and not in the server?